# Pinescript - How would I go about having a condition execute the first time it's met only?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How would I go about having a condition execute the first time it's met only? An example of what I want to achieve is as follows (this is just a snippit of my code):

```
if (RSILong)
    directionPoints := directionPoints + 1
if (RSIShort)
    directionPoints := directionPoints - 1
```

If it's possible, I'd like to be able to only update the directionPoints variable once (the first time the condition is true). Any help is appretiated.

I tried to have another variable what would be set to true/false depending on if it had already executed but it still was updating the variable more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for it to only count if the condition wasn't true on the bar before or if you want it to only count RSI long once until there is an RSI short signal.

You can make it so it only counts if the condition wasn't true on the bar before by doing something like this.

```
if rsilong and not rsilong[1]
    directionPoints := directionPoints + 1
if rsishort and not rsishort[1]
    directionPoints := directionPoints - 1
```

Comment: I took your advise and updated those conditions to use the "and not" condition and the directionPoints variable is getting updated properly, however, another problem has come up. Orders aren't being places when the directionPoints variable hits certain values. My code is below- any help is appreciated.

Comment: ```
if (directionPoints > 1)
 longConditionOne := true
 shortConditionOne := false
if (directionPoints < -1)
 longConditionOne := false
 shortConditionOne := true
if (allowTrade and canEnter and longConditionOne and not longConditionOne[1])
 enterLong := true
 enterShort := false
if (allowTrade and canEnter and shortConditionOne and not shortConditionOne[1])
 enterLong := false
 enterShort := true
```
Part 1

Comment: ```
if (enterLong and not enterLong[1])
 canEnter := strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades - 1) != bar_index
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 1.0)
if (enterShort and not enterShort[1])
    canEnter := strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades - 1) != bar_index
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, 1.0)
```
Part 2

Comment: Solved the above issue myself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out!